# Embedding mono - "Fatal error in GC": "Too many root sets"

Tags: dll, mono

I'm embedding mono in C++ application, and I'm linking it via dll library, which is then loaded into application via `LoadLibrary`.

When the application starts and the dll runtime linking happens, the mono runtime seems to fail to initialize itself with "Too many root sets" message. I'm unsure when and how the runtime itself is initialized (I thought it happens on `mono_jit_init`, but the error pops up before any call to any of the mono functions. It occurs exactly at LoadLibrary should I try load it manually instead of relying on `mono.lib` import library).

I succesfuly embedded it in standalone application, so I assume it is something specific to the way my dll is loaded by the application, but I don't know what exactly.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a limitation of the way the Boehm GC works in windows: it hooks to the operating system at LoadLibrary time to get notifications of the created threads and loaded libraries (this is why you get the issue at LoadLibrary() time and not on mono_jit_init()).

Or it may be that you have really many threads and libraries loaded by the time the GC is initialized. If you link the app to mono directly, does the problem go away? If yes, that should be your current workaround.

In the future (or if building mono from git) you may be able to use the SGen GC which shouldn't suffer from this problem.

Comment: Just performed the test with linking mono directly, has not succeeded, but at least this time it crashes (with no info at all) on the `mono_jut_init("Program.exe")` call. So I guess it's another problem.

Comment: As for the other problem, `mono_set_dirs` helped, so now it works.